# Can't find service because OSGi bundle isn't activated

Tags: spring, osgi, bundle, equinox, springsource-dm-server

I'm having a problem discovering services that are provided by some OSGi bundles that are not being activated.  Let me describe the situation:

- Bundle A defines interface X
- Bundles B, C, and D provide services that implement interface X

  - These bundles' services are registered via Spring DM, so they are only created when the bundle is activated and Spring DM initialized the application context defined in the bundle
- Bundle A is activated and at some point asks the service registry for services for interface X.  It doesn't find any, because bundles B, C, and D haven't been moved into the ACTIVE state (they are only RESOLVED).

I cannot seem to get bundles B, C, or D to start, and therefore register their services.  Forcing them to start by adding them to the `config.ini` is not an option, because there can be any number of bundles that are installed in the application (via an Eclipse p2-like update mechanism) that implement interface X.

The application is an Eclipse 3.5-based RCP app, using Spring 2.5.6 and Spring DM 1.2.1.

How do I force these bundles to be activated?

Comment: Could you provide some informations on the error messages you get?
And: Bundle A exports interface X, and Bundle B, C, D import it, right?

Comment: Yes, interface X is exported by bundle A, and imported by B, C, and D.  There aren't any error messages.  The query for services implementing X in the service registry just returns an empty list.

Comment: What's the cardinality you're requesting in `A`? If it's `1..N` you have a circular dependency.

Comment: The cardinality in `A` is `0..N`.  Could you elaborate on how `1..N` causes a circular dependency?  I don't quite understand that.

Comment: If it were `1..N` you'd *require* an instance from bundles `B` and `C` before you could start `A`, but `B` and `C` have a strict dependency on `A`, so none of the bundles would be able to come up. What happens if you manually refresh `A`, then `B` then `C`?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Starting the bundles manually works fine.  The services from B, C and D are available as expected.  It's getting them to start "on their own" that's the problem.

Comment: I recall something funny about 0..N not having a timing constraint, so basically because of your dependency hierarchy the bundles that depend on A aren't ever refreshed (so they can't start) and as such never publish their services... you might try looking for a way to force a refresh when A starts (not specifically on B and D).  The next step here is to show us some spring configs and manifest files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really have is a dependency hierarchy problem, your proposed hacky solution is really just a band-aid over the underlying issue.

What you should really consider is the architecture of your system, as effectively what you have is a circular dependency (re: discussion in comments your original post).  You have (like it or not) A requires services from (and in some sense depends on) B and C.  Meanwhile, B and C directly depend on A, and as such, *cannot* start until A comes up.

In the best case, you can write code in B and C to listen for the existence of A, but this at best masks (as I mentioned) the underlying issue.  What you should really consider is splitting A into two bundles, let's call them A1 and A2.

A1 should provide the interface which B and C require (depend on).  A2 should have listeners for the services B and C depend on.  At startup, if B and C are required services, A1 must be run, but A2 may start any time later, and everything should work.

Comment: I'm going to try out your suggestion and see what happens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to this problem, though it feels a bit hackish.

I ran across [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/spring-osgi/browse_thread/thread/3da3ace5e34829fc) where Adrian Colyer implied that an external "bundle watcher" could be responsible for activating bundles when they are installed into the framework.

So, my solution was to:

- Add a custom header to bundle B, C, and D's respective manifests, e.g., "MyApp-AutoStart: true"
- Create a bundle listener that responds when a bundle is moved into the RESOLVED state, and looks for the header
- If the header's value is "true," the bundle listener calls `bundle.start()`

Using this method, the bundles I want to be started are started without having to resort to using `config.ini`, and they can come and go as they please, but their services are available when queried.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at felix fileinstall, which watches a directory for bundles and automatically installs and starts them. When a file is deleted, the bundle is stopped and uninstalled as well.